# how to split the string into 3 strings and replace on the same place

Tags: python, list, split

I have list of lists: each list contains the string with one sentence in this sent there are uncleaned words like word;word so I need to make it clean like word ; word. the sypbol(;) shoud be returned as well

```
start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]
output=[]
for item in start:
    #print(item)
    for l in item:
        if ';' in l:
            l=l.split(";")
            l.append("")
            l[2]=l[1]
            l[1]=";"
            for i in l:
                item.append(i)
                output.append(item)
            #print(l)
        else:
            output.append(([item]))


start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]
output=[]
for item in start:
    #print(item)
    for l in item:
        if ';' in l:
            l=l.split(";")
            l.append("")
            l[2]=l[1]
            l[1]=";"
            for i in l:
                item.append(i)
                output.append(item)

        else:
            output.append(item)
```

the result that I want to get is like this:

```
output=[["lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12 ; lo"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to check for `;` by yourself or split the string if you want to keep it as a single string. You can just use `.replace` method and even list comprehension to do everything in the single line!

```
`output = [[inner_string.replace(";", " ; ")] for [inner_string] in start]`
```

How it works:

```
>>> start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]
>>> output = [[inner_string.replace(";", " ; ")] for [inner_string] in start]
>>> print(output)
[['lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui'], ['lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh'], ['lolo  mama12 ; lo']]
>>>
```

As for your current code, look into `.join`. ;) Another way of doing what you did is doing a split on `";"` and then joining on `" ; "`. Here also with list comprehension:

```
>>> output2 = [[" ; ".join(inner_string.split(";"))] for [inner_string] in start]
>>> print(output2)
[['lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui'], ['lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh'], ['lolo  mama12 ; lo']]
```

Please mind that both those solutions base on the fact that your inner lists consist of only 1 string. I can modify those for general usage if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace all `";"` by `" ; "` with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[0].replace(";", " ; ")], start))
```

Code:

```
# Input
start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]

# Output 
out = list(map(lambda x: [x[0].replace(";", " ; ")], start))
print(out)
# [['lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui'], ['lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh'], ['lolo  mama12 ; lo']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all occurences of ';' preceded or followed by 0 or more spaces by ' ; '. This way, you wouldn't add any unnecessary space if part of your string has already been 'cleaned', as would happen if you simply replace them.

```
import re

start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]

pattern = re.compile(r'\s*;\s*')
out  = [[pattern.sub(' ; ', sublist[0])] for sublist in start]
print(out)
# [['lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui'], ['lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh'], ['lolo  mama12 ; lo']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want the `word;word` to look like `word ; word`, to do this, you can just replace `';'` with `' ; '`:

```
start=[["lolo mama12;lo ushfudhsui"],["lolo mama12;lo lolo;jhdsjh" ],["lolo  mama12;lo"]]

clean = [[x.replace(';', ' ; ') for x in i] for i in start]
```

Output:

```
[['lolo mama12 ; lo ushfudhsui'],
 ['lolo mama12 ; lo lolo ; jhdsjh'],
 ['lolo  mama12 ; lo']]
```